# MacBook Pro mouse pauses every 1.5 seconds with external monitors

Tags: display, big-sur, mouse, hdmi, displayport

I have two [Samsung QHD 27"](https://www.coolblue.nl/en/product/876881/samsung-lf27t700qquxen.html) monitors plugged into my 2019 MacBook Pro 16", but noticed that when moving the mouse, the mouse cursor gets stuck around every 1.5 seconds. This is extremely frustrating while working.

I initially had the screens plugged into the two left USB-C ports via two USB-C to Startech HDMI cables. I tried plugging into different ports, for example both screens on the right 2 USB ports, one on the left, one on the right, but to no avail.

Yesterday afternoon the mouse pausing stopped for a couple of hours, but today, it's all happening again. I turned off Spotlight by disallowing Spotlight to index my harddrive, tried changing to different screen resolutions and refresh rates, but nothing helps. Tried closing every application I could, this even happens right from initial startup.

Recently, I purchased two USB-C to DisplayPort cables rated good enough for 8k, but that too didn't help.

Tried booting into Windows 10, no problem there, so it's definitely something in macOS.

I'm using macOS Big Sur version 11.5.2. No USB dock, screens are plugged into the ports directly.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: Can you plug the mouse directly in a USB-port in the machine?

Comment: Happens with both my USB-C mouse and built in track pad. Unplugged the mouse as well, same issue on the trackpad.

Comment: That looks like something else is going on.   Have you tried the Apple USB-C -> HDMI/USB adapter?

Comment: I haven't no, don't have an Apple adapter.

Comment: That might be your next attempt.

Comment: Also consider looking in the logs using Console to see if anything is written when you see the symptoms.